# Converting to valid urls which can be opened by open-uri

Tags: ruby

I need to open some webpages using open-uri in ruby and then parse the content of those pages using Nokogori.
I just did:

```
 require 'open-uri'
 content_file = open(user_input_url)
```

This worked for: `http://www.google.co.in`   and  `http://google.co.in`  but fails when user give inputs like `www.google.co.in` or `google.co.in`.

One thing i can do for such inputs i can append `http://` and `https://` and return the content of the page that opens. But this seems like a big hack to me.
Is there any better way to achieve this in ruby(i.e converting these user_inputs to valid open_uri urls).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
uri = URI("www.google.com")
if uri.instance_of?(URI::Generic)
    uri = URI::HTTP.build({:host => uri.to_s}) 
end
content_file = open(uri)
```

There are other ways as well see ref: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/HTTP.html

Comment: How the condition `uri == URI::Generic` can ever be true? Maybe you mean `uri.instance_of?(URI::Generic)`?

Comment: Yes I do or uri.class

Comment: well, that gives me `URI::InvalidComponentError: bad component(expected host component)`

Comment: @sandric I just tested on ruby 2.3.1 and it works fine. Perhaps you're missing the `require 'open-uri'` at the top? What URI did you test with?

Comment: @sandric `//lala.com` is not a valid URI according to the RFC `https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt`. Why are you using an invalid format?

Answer (score 3):

Prepend the scheme if not present and then use `URI` which will check the URL validity:

```
require 'uri'

url = 'www.google.com/a/b?c=d#e'
url.prepend "http://" unless url.start_with?('http://', 'https://')
url = URI(url) # it will raise error if the url is not valid
open url
```

Unfortunately, an "object oriented" version of what you need is more verbose and even more hackish:

```
require 'uri'

case url = URI.parse 'www.google.com/a/b?c=d#e'
when URI::HTTP, URI::HTTPS
  # no-op
when URI::Generic
  # We need to split u.path at the first '/', since URI::Generic interprets
  # 'www.google.com/a/b' as a single path
  host, path = url.path.split '/', 2
  url = URI::HTTP.build host:     host         ,
                        path:     "/#{path}"   ,
                        query:    url.query    ,
                        fragment: url.fragment
else
  raise "unsupported url class (#{url.class}) for #{url}"
end
open url
```

If you accept suggestions, don't break your head too much on this: I faced this matter often and I'm quite sure there aren't "polished" ways to do it

Comment: You have an uninitialized variable `u` in your latter example, I guess it should be `url`.

Comment: i ended up adding `http://` as suggested. Thanks for the suggestion of not to struggle too much to get a 'polished' solution :).

Comment: Thank you for the grammar fix :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to prepend `http` to the urls, without an explicit scheme the uri could be anything, e.g. a local file. A uri is not necessarily an http url.

You can check either by using the `URI` class or by using a regex:

```
user_input_url = URI.parse(user_input_url).scheme ?
    user_input_url :
    "http://#{user_input_url}"

user_input_url = user_input_url =~ /https?:\/\// ?
    user_input_url :
    "http://#{user_input_url}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def instance_to_hash(instance)
  hash = {}
  instance.instance_variables.each {|var| hash[var[1..-1].to_sym] = instance.instance_variable_get(var) }
  hash
end

def url_compile(url)
  # if url without 'http://', 'https://', '//' at start of string
  # then prepend '//'
  url.prepend '//' unless url.start_with?('http://', 'https://', '//')
  uri = URI(url)
  if uri.instance_of?(URI::Generic) # if scheme nil then assume it HTTPS
    uri = URI::HTTPS.build(instance_to_hash(uri))
  end
  uri
end
```